# Track button click, GTM

Tags: button, events, google-tag-manager

first time here and completely new to coding. I want to track button clicks on my website in Tag Manager. The button is a thumbnail in an image gallery. It's the only video in the gallery and I want to see how popular it is compared to the images. The trigger type is 'All elements' and I tried to use Click Class as a trigger. The problem is that all the thumbnails in the gallery have the same class. So there is no way to identify the video thumbnail. Can't use Click URL either since it's not a link. It doesn't have an ID either. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to use a more specific CSS selector to the element you're wanting to trigger on. Most modern browsers can help you out there. If you right click the element you want to capture clicks on, you'll have something along the lines of "Inspect Element" as an option.

### Chrome Example

In Chrome, this appears at the bottom of the list under "Developer Tools -> Inspect" as I see when I do the same for the Ask Question button on this page.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools -> Inspect Context Menu]

### Firefox Example

In Firefox, this is just the Inspect option at the bottom of the context menu.

[image: Firefox Developer Tools -> Inspect Context Menu]

Other browsers will generally be similar. Selecting that option will open the Developer console, but will generally auto-select the element you selected from the page. In Chrome (again, other browsers will be similar), right click the element and select Copy -> Copy selector.

[image: Copy Selector from Context Menu in DevTools]

This will copy a more specific selector than just the element's CSS ID to your clipboard. You might want to copy this down somewhere temporarily.

Back to GTM - You're right that you want to use the "Click - All Elements" trigger type here. Select the "Some Clicks" option so we can apply a filter to the event. Set the left-most option to "Click Event", the middle option to "matches CSS selector" and the paste the value for the CSS selector you've got in your clipboard. Save that, and you're good to go!

Now, this assumes that you're not doing a lot of dynamic work on your page. The CSS selector your browser gives you will be accurate for that very moment, but it may very well specify classes that change dynamically (e.g. if you're using a single-page application like Angular or Vue), so you might need to tweak it a bit to be generic enough that you can capture the element, but not so specific that it looks for a particular class that might change each pageload.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The issue that I'm having is that all the CSS selectors are the same. When copying the selector for the video thumbnail it's exactly the same as the image thumbnails. So I need to find something that is more unique. Is it possible to copy the whole code snippet for the object/image under inspect? What veriable can I use instead?

Comment: Assuming your images are always displayed in the same order every time your (presumably JS-based) thumbnail selector loads up (since your tracking wouldn't otherwise make a lot of sense), you could instead use offsets on the selector. Assuming your selector (per my instructions) looks something like "#thumbnails > ul > li", append an offset selector to the end giving you "#thumbnails > ul > li:nth-child(8)" to select the specific element from a set of common elements.